# how to take variable from function in tcl

Tags: variables, tcl, proc

i make a function like this

```
proc function1 {} {
    set x 10
}
```

and i want to use x in second function
like this

```
proc function2 {x} {
   set y [expr x + 10]
} 
puts [function2 x]
```

invalid command name "x" this is the error i got

i tried to write `puts [function2 function1.x]` and `puts [function2 $x]`

i got same error

like it can not read x from first function

how can i solve this error?

Comment: As `set x 10` is the last command in `function1`, the result of that command (10) is returned. So for your example you could use: `puts [function2 [function1]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` variable in `function1` is local to it and is destroyed when the function returns. You can use

```
proc function1 {} {
    global x
    set x 10
}
```

to make it a [global variable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/global.html) instead so that it can be seen by a later top-level `puts [function2 x]`. Or use `set ::x 10` to explicitly refer to the variable in the global namespace. Or use [`variable x`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/variable.html) to bind it to the proc's namespace instead of the global one if they're different.

Comment: if my variable is list can i make it global also by using keyword global ?

Comment: @shaheen Doesn't matter what's in the variable (unless it's an array; you can't make a specific element global, just the whole thing)

Comment: `set sel [atomselect top "resid $start to $end and resname $name"]`
when i write global sel 
and use this sel in another function i got the error of invalid command name sel

Comment: edit : the error now is invalid command name atomselect0

Comment: I have no idea what `atomselect` is.

Comment: `atomselect` is not a standard Tcl command, but rather one provided by some library or application.

Comment: @DonalFellows yes i'm using VMD to execute the script 
the whole second function depend on the sel variable from first function 
i tried global and i tried upvar and i got the same error invalid command name atomselect
by the way the select statement work in it's function so i don't know where is the error

Answer (score 0):

Consider `function1` which set `x` and return the value of `x` as well. In order to use that in `function2`, you need to call:

```
puts [function2 [function1]]
```

By the way, `function2` has a bug: You need `$x` to get the value, not just `x`.

```
proc function2 {x} {
   set y [expr $x + 10]   ;# <--- $x, not x
}
```